# SELECT Query does not work for retrieving PDF in Mobile Application

Tags: javascript, html, pdf.js

I am building a HTML5 based hybrid application and need to download, store and display PDF documents from a backend Sharepoint server. For viewing PDF I am using PDF.js. Download and storing of PDF documents is working fine and I get corresponding success messages.
Now when I try to SELECT the data from local database, the query is failing and I do not know where. The code used to retrieve data is same as mentioned in the [PDF.js example](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/learning/helloworld.html)

Below is the code for Downloading, Storing and Retrieving the data which I am using:

```
    function getRawData(){

                            var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHTTP.open('GET','http://servername.com/TestDoc.pdf',true);
                            xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +"Base64String"); 
                            xmlHTTP.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

                            xmlHTTP.onload = function(e)
                            {
                                var arr = new Uint8Array(this.response);
                                saveToDb(arr);
                            };
                                xmlHTTP.send();
                        //This function is successful
                        }


                        function saveToDb(rwdt){
                            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO pdfdata (rawdata) VALUES (?)',[rwdt],SuccessInsert,errorInsert);
                            });
                        //This function is successful
                        }

                        function SuccessInsert(tx,result){
                            alert("Last inserted ID = " + result.insertId);//This is triggered
                        }

function retrieveFromTable(){
                        db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM pdfdata',[],showpdfNew,selecterror);
                        });                        
                    }
function showpdfNew(tx,rs){
                        var r = rs.rows.item(0);
                        var url = r['rawdata'];
                        alert("Alerts work only till here");
                        PDFJS.workerSrc = 'js/pdf.worker.js';
                        // Asynchronous download PDF
                        PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
                            // Fetch the first page
                            pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
                                var scale = 1.5;
                                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
                                // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                                var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
                                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                                canvas.width = viewport.width;
                                var renderContext = {
                                    canvasContext: context,
                                    viewport: viewport
                                };
                                page.render(renderContext);
                            });
                        });
                    }
```

The corresponding files -> pdf.js and pdf.worker.js are included in the project folder and also in the index.html. HTML page is only of 3 simple buttons with *onclick* to the functions shown above.
Can anyone please point out what is missing in the above logic?

**Edit**:
If I try to display the PDF directly in the mobile application (instead of storing in the local DB and then opening) then it opens without any issue.

Comment: What's r['rawdata']? If it's not a Uint8Array use `var url = {data: r['rawdata']};`

Comment: @async5 : Thanks for the hint. I am now changed the function a bit like: var r = rs.rows.item(0); var url = r.rawdata; This r.rawdata gives me a uint8Array. However, still I am not able to display the PDF. the code simply stops processing and I do not know why & where.

Comment: Set debugger into break on all exceptions mode (even on caught) and mention all exception it throws until it stops. Also, try adding second argument to the then() which will be called during exceptions.